# Adobe Illustrator selecting a group of selected objects using the layers panel

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In the screenshot of the Adobe illustrator layers panel, I have highlighted some items within a grouped object. Is it possible to then be able to select those using a keyboard shortcut or menu item as apposed to having to shift click each individual meatball switch. Of course the Group switch could be clicked on but it would be a real use to be able to highlight a few items in a group and then select them.[image: Screenshot of the Adobe layers panel]?

Answer (score 1):

Would the small circle switch at the far right of the (group) layer not select just those items on the layer? Sorry might not be what you meant but that circle when selected picks only those items on that layer. You can also lock ones you dont want to select to get more specific in your mass selection

Answer (score 1):

No, You *have* to shift-click. Layer *highlights* have no correlation to object selection. And there's no internal method to select objects based upon layer panel highlights.

However, for that *Group* you could merely click the circle to the right of the group.... all objects within the groups will be selected.

Comment: Thanks for the information. One useful keyboard shortcut I learned the other day was to command or control click on an object multiple times to select different objects behind in the stacking order.